# Collab Subversion Edge Updates

Tags: collabnet, subversion-edge

I am in dire need of the updates for Apache, it is recommended that we don't just upgrade Apache on this system as it can break it, on that note, I have reached out to Digital.ai multiple times and they haven't responded and i can't find a phone number for them either. I had read somewhere that Subversion edge was community supported now but I have yet to find it or if someone out there has a good recommendation to change the server to something that is like this that would be great something that can import my existing repositories in to the new program that would be great, but still any help would be great here i am at a loss and it is a critical vulnerability that needs to be patched.

Help with the community page where Subversion Edge from Collab where it is still developed, I have searched google for both of this and the phone number to Digital.AI just need some help I can't get it to update from the old repositories that are in the system as they don't exist anymore. If someone has new repositories that would be great too. I have tried everything i can here !

Answer (score 0):

The server product "Subversion Edge" is no longer available. And as far as I know, upgrading its components individually and manually isn't an option (frankly, it doesn't make sense to just upgrade Apache HTTP Server while leaving other components outdated which I guess was your idea).

If you're in need of an alternative, modern and fully supported Subversion server solution, consider trying out [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/). VisualSVN Server utilizes the latest versions of all necessary components and is actively developed. It provides a seamless option for migrating your repositories. Please see the following pages:

- [VisualSVN Server | Getting Started](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/)
- [VisualSVN Server | Documentation](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/documentation/)
- [KB10: Importing Repositories into VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/)

Please contact support@visualsvn.com if you need a more detailed guidance on migrating your repositories from Subversion Edge into VisualSVN Server.

PS Although I'm pretty sure it's clear from my SO profile, I feel that I have to explicitly mention that I work as a support engineer with the VisualSVN Team.